# Trying to open Diary on startup but Emacs is launching in split screen, how can I stop it

Tags: start-up, window-splitting

I have `(diary)` setup in my `.emacs` file so that it will launch diary on launch but it always launches in horizontal split screen with fancy diary mode on bottom and Scratch on top. I've inhibited the welcome/splash screen and inhibited Scratch but then Messages just takes its place. To my knowledge there isn't anything in my `.emacs` file that would launch it in split screen. Below is everything I have for my diary setup.

```
;minibuffer notifications
(appt-activate 1)
(diary)

;desktop notifications
(require 'notifications)

(defcustom appt-notification-bus :session
  "dbus notifications"
  :version "29.05"
  :group 'appt-notification
  :type '(choice (const :tag "Session bus" :session) string))

(defun user/appt-display (min-to-app new-time msg)
  "sends notifications"
  (notifications-notify :bus appt-notification-bus
            :title (format "Appointment in %s minutes" min-to-app)
            :body (format "%s" msg)
            :replaces-id nil
            :app-icon notifications-application-icon
            :timeout 8000
            :desktop-entry "diary"))

(setq appt-disp-window-function (function user/appt-display))

(appt-activate t)
(setq-default diary-file "/home/alarm/.emacs.d/diary"
          appt-display-format 'window
          appt-display-duration 60
          appt-audible t
          appt-display-interval 15
          appt-message-warning-time 15
          display-time-24hr-format t
          display-time-day-and-date t)
```

Comment: Instead of asking people to debug your init file, please consider narrowing it down to just what's needed to show the problem. (You can do that by bisecting it.) Thx.

Comment: Kinda like I said, I don't think there is anything in there causing it to go split screen and the only thing really relevant is the `(diary)`. So I may as well remove the link, just thought it might be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the variable `initial-buffer-choice` to be your choice of buffer: `*scratch*` is the default if that is nil and you are inhibiting the splash screen.

The doc string of the variable says:

> Buffer to show after starting Emacs.
> If the value is nil and ‘inhibit-startup-screen’ is nil, show the
> startup screen.  If the value is a string, switch to a buffer
> visiting the file or directory that the string specifies.  If the
> value is a function, call it with no arguments and switch to the buffer
> that it returns.  If t, open the ‘*scratch*’ buffer.
>
> When ‘initial-buffer-choice’ is non-nil, the startup screen is
> inhibited.

But there are some additional wrinkles. I think the sequencing in your code is wrong: you need to set up the diary before invoking `(diary)`. So I suggest the following rearrangement of the code:

```
;;;desktop notifications
(require 'notifications)

;;; diary setup
(setq-default diary-file "/home/nick/.config/emacs/diary"
          display-time-24hr-format t
          display-time-day-and-date t)
(diary)

(setq initial-buffer-choice diary-file)

;;;minibuffer notifications
(defcustom appt-notification-bus :session
  "dbus notifications"
  :version "29.05"
  :group 'appt-notification
  :type '(choice (const :tag "Session bus" :session) string))

(defun user/appt-display (min-to-app new-time msg)
  "sends notifications"
  (notifications-notify :bus appt-notification-bus
            :title (format "Appointment in %s minutes" min-to-app)
            :body (format "%s" msg)
            :replaces-id nil
            :app-icon notifications-application-icon
            :timeout 8000
            :desktop-entry "diary"))

(setq-default
          appt-display-format 'window
          appt-display-duration 60
          appt-audible t
          appt-display-interval 15
          appt-message-warning-time 15)

(setq appt-disp-window-function (function user/appt-display))

(appt-activate t)
```

That initializes the diary variables, calls the `diary` function to open the diary file and create a buffer for it and sets the initial buffer choice to the buffer specicied by the `diary-file` variable.

Then we set up the appointment reminders (and get rid of one of the two calls to `appt-activate` - we only call it *after* the `appt` variables have been initialized - another sequencing problem with the code).

I should point out that although I've tested the above code to make sure it produces a single window with the diary in it, I have *NOT* tested the appointment stuff (which is really irrelevant to the question).

Comment: Sweet, thanks! This seems to be working just fine!